# Install Directory Path

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, installation, wix3.5

I use `WIX` to create an `MSI` installer for a `DLL`.

The installer allows the user to browse for a directory to install the program.

How can I get the path that the user has chosen?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you want to 'get' the path?

Comment: @Paul Zahra, I have to use it in my program, trying to use some files that I've strored in the installation directory.

Comment: Can't you put the files you want in a directory and then use a relative path?

Comment: @PaulZahra, But I would like to allow the user to choose himself where to install the program. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, but inside the 'install' folder that the user chooses have a folder 'myfiles' and put the files you want to use in there... then perhaps you can reference them in a relative (not absolute file path, relative to the installation directory) manner?

Comment: @PaulZahra, How can I do so?

Comment: A possible design issue is here is that data files should not even be in the Program Files folder (the default location) with the binaries. Store them in (say) the User's Application Data folder, which has a corresponding Environment.SpecialFolder you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using something like the following to get your install location.

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

Comment: Zahre, Please let me try it.

Comment: I don't see how that could be useful.  This implies the DLL is executing so whats the problem that's being solved?  Is this a COM server or a plugin for some other program?  Something clearly already found it.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter, If I have the path where the DLL id executing I know where the user preferred to locate the installation directory.